# Limits-related question

Tags: calculus, limits

If I know that:

•$f(x)$ is an increasing function
•$x<x+a$
•$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x+a)$

Can I conclude that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\infty$ ?

Sorry if the question is silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A counterexample is $-1/x$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)=\arctan x.$ What do you get?